# easy way of preventing multiple users of working on the same task

Tags: design-patterns, functions, ui

Our client has a software, where tickets come in. Multiple employees are responsible for answering these tickets (via phone), in a short amount of time (call back within X minutes).

What would be the simplest way of preventing 2 employees calling back the same client / working on the same ticket?

The client suggested, that tickets should be automatically assigned to specific users, according to who is online, and who has the least tickets.

Is there a more obvious and simpler solution?

Answer (score 5):

Normally a ticket system to have states for each ticket, minimally consisting of 'open' and 'closed' (though it could be much more complex).

Have another state called 'in progress', along with an assignee (user). When someone goes to pick up the ticket, you'll switch it to 'in progress' and set that user as the assignee.

The trick is to explicitly check the state during transition, in an atomic way. So for example, if you are using SQL, you'd do something like this:

```
UPDATE ticket SET 
  state = 'inprogress',
  assignee = @thisUserId,
WHERE ticketId = @ticketId
  AND state = 'open'
  AND assignee = @currentAssignee
```

The two last WHERE lines ensure you don't have conflicts: if two users both decide to take on the ticket at the same time, only one of these queries can possibly work -- the other will fail, because the state and/or assignee have changed (causing now rows to match the update condition).

You can detect this condition (0 rows updated) and then show a message saying something to the effect of "Sorry, ticket can no longer be assigned" and reload the current state from the database.

Answer (score 3):

In what you're describing, how does pre-assigning them to currently busy employees help at all (the client suggestion)?

There should be a queue of work, which an employee takes from whenever they have a free moment (to return a call).  This is what's known as just in time, or in other words, dynamic.

The other way, you don't know when they'll become free, you're really just guessing, and you could be right or could be wrong!

Comment: pre assigning them to the least busy user, is what I meant. So there are no two users looking at the same ticket, or trying to quickly click in order to get the ticket before the next user.

Comment: Preassignment by any algorithm is still just an unnecessary guess.  The least busy employee is not guaranteed to be the first available.   And there is no advantage to preassignment compared with just in time decision making.  Just in time delayes decision making until the best information is available, so the idea is to wait until the last possible moment to make a decision.

Comment: @ErikEidt And none of the issues you raise may be cared about by the client.  Pre-assignment can be valid, if it works and the customer is happy with it.  It could be the typical call is very short, and this works out fine.

Comment: queue of work is what they have now, the problem with this is, that multiple people try to click on the same task and it gets annoying. On the other hand, sometimes all are busy and tickets pile up.

Comment: They should just click an anonymous box that gives them the next in the queue, no?

Comment: So, basically, users don't choose a ticket, but click a button "im ready" and the system assigns them then the ticket? This is actually a very good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Write the 'ticket' on a piece of paper. You are only allowed to work on it when you actually have the physical ticket

Comment: damn computers always giving us trouble +1

Comment: Not really an appropriate answer for a software engineering Q&A.  And it completely falls down as soon as the people working tickets are in two different physical locations, unless you want to pay to move paper around.  Which is why it should be done in the software.

Comment: I submit that this is the only possible correct answer given the level of information known. ie 'the client has a software', which presumably doesn't include the normal workflow which would make this question redundant and 'tickets are answered via phone'.

Comment: The original post seemed to use the word "ticket" as a generic abstraction. 
 This answer is a reminder to take the notion of "ticket" or "kanban" literally enough that it can be used as a "semaphore".